# How to restrict insert to table depending on another table column value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have table `Enrolled` (studentid, sectionid), and another table `Section` (sectionid, capacity). I want to restrict insert into the `Enrolled` table depending on `Section` table's `Capacity` column so that the section's capacity is not exceeded.

Please see the sample screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Show some of your data. Any code you created? What is the impenetrable capacity?

Comment: sorry no sql code i have created yet. capacity is integer no and it can be for some section id 20 and for another section id 30. so it is random.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/oxrnxq   Please see the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a trigger such as:

```
create trigger trg_enrolled 
on enrolled 
for update, insert 
as
-- your logic 
if exists( business logic to see if over capacity)
begin
   raiserror ('Class at capacity',16,1);
   rollback transaction
   return
end
```

Comment: hi what could be the business logic? I am unable to write this logic. can u pls just write the business logic inside if condition according to my screenshot . then my problem will be solved.

Comment: How do you know when the class is over capacity. You need two columns 1 for current enrollment and the other for capacity. If you had such columns you could do someting like: Select * from section where totalenrolled = capacity

Comment: You may also try Sai Puli's solution which computes current enrollment on the fly but you have to use the trigger type I used.

Comment: Hi ur idea works great for me and my life is easy again now. just i did a little modification at business logic. Thanks a lot dear.

Answer (score 0):

add a before insert trigger to the Enrolled table that checks the capacity.

Comment: Can u pls give me a trigger according to my sample table at screenshot? http://prntscr.com/oxrnxq

Comment: see the reply above from benjamin moskovits.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a trigger, on insertion have a where clause that checks if count()+1>Section .capacity

```
INSERT INTO Enrolled
SELECT @studentid,@sectionid FROM (select * from section where sectionid=@sectionid) s,(select count(*) count from enrolled where sectiondi=@sectionid ) e
WHERE e.count+1<s.capacity
```

Comment: I want trigger. Will be happy if u can give me a trigger for this.

Comment: This is a nice solution but the logic will have to be maintained for both insert and update. There is no feedback that it fails (unless you follow up with a @@rowcount and check if its = 0 and then throw an error.

Comment: my concern is that we are doing someones homework for them.

Comment: An insert can involve multiple rows at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INSTEAD OF` clause in trigger.

Something like below...

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER course_is_full
ON Enrolled
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @enrolledStudents INT
    DECLARE @capacity INT

--Get the already enrolled count
    SELECT @enrolledStudents = COUNT(1) 
    FROM Enrolled 
    WHERE SectionId = (SELECT SectionId FROM INSERTED)

--Get the course capacity
    SELECT @capacity = Capacity 
    FROM Section 
    WHERE SectionId = (SELECT SectionId FROM INSERTED)

    IF (@enrolledStudents >= @capacity) 
      BEGIN    
        RAISERROR (N'This course is full'); 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RETURN 
      END
  END
```

Comment: This wont work. IF the number is under the 'instead of' trigger will not update enrolled.

Comment: Remember that an insert can be more than just one row.